# Add directory to CMake project without CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator

I have the following project structure:

- CMakeLists.txt (top level)
- include

  - source.h
- examples

  - CMakeLists.txt
  - example.cpp
- src

  - CMakeLists.txt
  - source.cpp

Top level `CMakeLists.txt` includes both `src` and `examples` using `add_subdirectory`. I want to do the same with `include` directory. I have no problem using the header files from `include`. What I want is to be able to see `include` directory in my IDE. Currently, QtCreator doesn't show `include` directory if I open the top level CMake file with it.

I know that I can add dummy `CMakeLists.txt` but that's a bit meh. Don't want to do this for code readers sanity sake.

Answer (score 0):

add `include_directories(include/)` in your toplevel `CMakeLists.txt` just before using `add_subdirectory`

Comment: I'm already doing this (target_include_directories is a better way to do this TBH). The point is to force IDE to show include directory in the project structure.